# Upgrade python in virtualenv over system python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I am working on a project for which I have python 3.5 as system python and a virtual env, but unfortunately one of the dependencies of the project requires python >3.7. Is there any way to create a virtual environment with python 3.5 and then upgrade python inside the venv to a version > 3.7?

Comment: Create a new VENV using 3.7, everything else might cause a lot of (erroneous) side effects.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible to upgrade the Python version within a virtual environment (venv). The version of Python used in a virtual environment is determined when the environment is created, and it cannot be changed later.

Comment: What is that dependency? If it worked previously, you can try installing an older version of it that supports 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you can do it directly like that, but maybe you can give it a try by creating a new venv with > 3.7 version and then use your project accordingly there? Of course you may have to install the new python version in your system for you to use it within the virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to install and use multiple Python versions without affecting your system Python.

Then you can create a new virtual environment with Python 3.7 and install the new dependencies in there.

The gist would be to:

1. Install pyenv,
2. Install Python 3.7 using pyenv: `pyenv install 3.7.`
3. Create a new virtual environment: `pyenv virtualenv <python_version> <environment_name>`.
4. Activate the virtual environment: `pyenv local <environment_name>`
5. Install your dependencies: `pip install -r requirements.txt`. You might get some errors here due if some of the packages aren't compatible with 3.7. Look up the packages on pypi and find a version that is compatible. Be sure to check the package's release docs to see if any major changes were made that you need to adjust for.

See [this article](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/) for further explanations.

Comment: Nice. But can you "upgrade python inside the venv" with pyenv?

Comment: No, but from the question text it sounds like the poster's main goal is to run a higher version of Python without affecting their system Python. They might have assumed that the way to do it was to upgrade the current virtual environment itself and might not be aware of other alternatives.

Comment: It is exactly what you said, I wasn't aware of the alternative and thought that I had to upgrade the current venv. As soon as I can, I will try this method, thank you very much